# On message recieve from websocket without causing 'Websocket: Close 1011'

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I'm trying to subscribe to an event from a client to a server. I can subscribe to the event using JavaScript but when I use `Golang` and the `Gorilla Websocket library` I get a

> 'websocket: close 1011 (internal server error)'

every time I start a read from the socket.

I tried using the `/x/websocket` library as well but when I tried to read from the socket I end up hanging and I dont get the '1011' error.

If I use this JavaScript code on my browser it works:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
        var socket = new WebSocket("ws://blehip:blehpport");

        function send(data) {
            socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }

        socket.onopen = function() {
            send({
                action: 'subscribe',
                auth_token: 'Bleh',
                request_id: 'Bleh',
                data: {
                    account_id: 'bleh',
                    binding: "bleh"
                }
            });
        }

        socket.onmessage = function(raw_message) {
            var json_data = JSON.parse(raw_message.data);

            console.log(json_data);
        };

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get a stream of JSON objects in real time.

This is my small Golang, Gorilla/Websockets script

```
func main() {
    var server = flag.String("server", "blehIP:BlehPort", "server address")

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    flag.Parse()

    url := url.URL {
        Scheme: "ws",
        Host: *server,
        Path: "",
    }

    conn, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(url.String(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Dial Error: ", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    payload := []byte(`{"action":"subscribe",`+
                       `"auth_token":"` + bleh + `",`+
                       `"request_id":"` + bleh + `",`+
                       `"data": {`+
                                `"account_id":"` + bleh + `",`+
                                `"binding":"` + bleh + `"}`+
                      `}`)

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer conn.Close()
        defer wg.Done()

        err = conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, payload)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Write Error: ", err)
            return
        }

        m := frame{}
        err := conn.ReadJSON(&m)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("WebScoket closed.", err)
            return
        }


        // msg := string(bytes[:])
        fmt.Printf("%v", m)
    }()
    wg.Wait()

    return
}
```

> The error returned is: WebSocket closed. websocket: close 1011
>   (internal server error)

Comment: The Go program looks correct, but you don't show the strings substituted into payload.  Is it possible that the result is invalid JSON?   The Javascript version will correctly escape values.

Comment: @CeriseLimón You're right. Welp.... Thanks